# Das seltenste Wort der deutschen Sprache

Tags: vocabulary, dictionary, curiosity

Im Rahmen einer Diskussion zu einem anderen Thema hier in diesem Marktplatz sprachlichen Nutz- und Trivialwissens stößt man auf folgenden Teil einer Antwort:

> People coin terms for things they address frequently. For things that are no topic of communication, there are no words, usually. (Interesting question: is there a word in any human language relating to a thing about which nobody speaks?)

In der Tat, die Frage interessiert mich. Vielleicht nicht in der ironischen Form wie oben (klar, ein Wort für ein Ding, über das niemand spricht, wird es nicht wirklich geben), aber leicht umformuliert lässt sich vielleicht doch sinnvoll fragen:

Kann man eine halbwegs stichhaltige Aussage treffen, welches in der deutschen Sprache das am seltensten benützte Wort wäre? Oder von mir aus das von am wenigsten Leuten gekannte?

(Ich nehme an, man müsste die Suche auf Wörter  beschränken, die irgendwo festgehalten und verzeichnet sind und damit eine quasi *verbuchte* Existenz führen. - Ich nehme weiter an, man müsste ein Reihe von Regeln aufstellen, was hier noch als "Wort" durchgehen soll. Eigennamen von Menschen, Dingen, Orten etc. wird man wohl ausnehmen.)

Comment: Idiom vllt. _"Irda"_ ist z.B. selbst hier wenig verstanden, oder gebraucht. Sicherlich nicht das _seltenste Wort_.

Comment: Tja. Was ist nun ein "Irda"... ? (Das ist das Dumme an seltenen Wörtern... man kennt sie nicht...)

Comment: Altbayrisch _Dienstag_ (heute sozusagen ;-)) Ich kenne das Wort auch nur durch lustige Zufälle, obwohl ich mit bayrisch aufgewachsen bin.

Comment: Würdest Du die Suche auch zeitlich begrenzen? Und wenn ja, wie? Es gibt sicher etliche Begriffe, deren Benutzungshäufigkeit sich über die Zeit ändert - würdest Du das irgendwie mitteln?

Comment: @Marzipanherz Sehr guter Einwand. Ich bin immer noch am Zweifeln, ob die Frage definitiv beantwortbar ist (im Sinne von _Frage und (eindeutiger) Antwort_).

Comment: @Christian _"Kann man eine halbwegs stichhaltige Aussage treffen ..."_ Eigentlich ist das fast schon eine Meta-Frage.

Comment: Ich bin für "Frützl", weil ausser hier grade habe ich es noch nirgends gesehen ;) (das ist natürlich Unsinn, zeigt aber indirekt, wie absurd die Frage ist). Irgend eine Anordnung von Lauten oer Bichstaben kann erst dann ein Wort *werden*, wenn sie hinreichend oft zur Bezeichnung von irgendetwas genutzt wird. Genausogut könntest du nach dem schwarzesten Weiß fragen. Diese Frage gehört eher nach Philosophy.

Comment: Es wird ein Wort gesucht, bei dem schon in einem uralten Wörterbuch "veraltet" dranstand, und heute seltsamerweise immer noch. Ich würde jetzt irgendwas in Richtung Mitgift oder Brautkauf denken, aber das Kranzgeld wurde ja auch erst vor relativ kurzer Zeit abgeschafft. (Warum: Weil das einfach nicht mehr "in" ist, aber nicht so ungebräuchlich, dass es völlig aus der Welt wäre.)

Comment: **Fregattenkapitänsunterhose** liefert bislang keinen einzigen Google-Treffer. Ich halte das also für ein recht seltenes Wort.

Comment: Das ist offentsichtlich **keine** Meta-Frage. Bitte nicht einen falschen *Close-Vote*-Grund angeben.

Comment: @tofro   Ja, du hast ganz recht, ein Wort im Sinne der Frage kann erst ein Wort sein, wenn es hinreichend oft benützt wird... oder aber wenigstens irgendwo als einmal in Benützung gewesen dokumentiert ist. Mit einer Bemerkung in dieser Richtung hatte ich die Frage ja auch - genau aus diesem Grund - präzisiert.

Comment: @Janka  - Dein Lösungsansatz gefällt mir. In so eine Richtung dachte ich auch. Wörter, die schon in den frühesten Wörterbüchern als "veraltet" o.ä. markiert sind, es aber z.B. bis heute in die Standardwerke der Wortsammelkunst geschafft haben... Begriffe aus heute nicht mehr üblichen Rechtspraktiken wären wohl gute Kandidaten. Sie sind recht universal verbreitet gewesen, haben ihre Relevanz aber verloren, sind aber auch schriftlich wohldokumentiert.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Damit stellst du eine Frage hierhin, von der du sagst, dass sie nicht beantwortet werden kann, ohne weitere Randbedingungen zu spezifizieren (was du nicht tust) - Damit ist deine Frage leider nicht zu beantworten (denn wer ausser dir sollte in der Lage sein, diese Randbedingungen aufzustellen?)

Comment: @scienceponder  Danke für diesen Vorschlag mit der Kapitänskleidung. Allerdings kann man natürlich durch Zusammenkettung aller möglichen Nomen neue Nomen schaffen, die es bisher nicht gab. Solche Wörter würde ich ausschließen, sonst kommt man vom Zipfelchen aufs Wipfelchen. Es müssten wohl Wörter sein, die irgendwo in einem Wörterbuch o.ä. schon mal notiert wurden. Oder von mir aus auch einer Anthologie der Dichtkunst (das wäre ja ein Ort, wo man Neologismen, die aber verschriftlich sind, erwarten darf).

Comment: @tofro    Ich denke, die geneigte Leser- und Schreiberschaft hier wäre findig genug, eine - wie du ganz richtig bemerkst - nicht ganz präzise Frage im Zuge des Antwortens noch entsprechend zurechtzupräzisieren. Dass bestimmte Kriterien anzulegen sind, ist klar. Ich habe diese Kriterien offengelassen, denn ich habe es als Teil der Frage verstanden, solche Kriterien vorzuschlagen. Vielleicht ein Fehler.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Das mag sein, dass das Publikum in der Lage wäre, solche Kriterien aufzustellen - aber so funktioniert GSE halt einfach nicht - Die Fragen werden gestellt und beantwortet, nicht *hindiskutiert*. Ganz einfach deshalb, weil's hinterher nicht mehr deine Frage wäre, oder andersrum, die Frage wird *beliebig*, wenn man beim Antworten die Randbedingungen aufstellt.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Du hast den Punkt, auf den ich aufmerksam machen wollte, verstanden.

Comment: @tofro: Naja, man kann danach fragen, ob es überhaupt möglich ist, sinnvolle Kriterien aufzustellen oder ob es irgendwelche inhärenten Problem damit gibt. Dies ist auch genau die Frage, die die existierenden Antworten beantworten.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Kann man. Tut er aber nicht. Die Antworten sind zwar hilfreich und m.A. nach auch richtig, beantworten aber die gestellte Frage nicht. So, wie die Frage gestellt ist, kann man entweder mit dem seltensten Wort oder "geht nicht" antworten.

Answer (score 8):

Die minimale Häufigkeit mit der ein Wort benutzt werden kann ist 1. Wörter mit dieser Frequenz werden *Hapax Legomena* genannt, und in einem beliebigen Text wird in etwa die Hälfte aller Wörter diese Frequenz haben (laut Zipf's Gesetz).

Mit anderen Worten, ein Großteil der Wörter kommt sehr selten vor. Und besonders 'nutzlose' werden oft als Kuriositäten paradoxerweise besonders häufig verwendet.

Eine Definition über Anzahl von Sprechern die ein Wort kennen ist ebenfalls problematisch, da es eine Sprache an sich nicht gibt; jeder Sprecher hat seine/ihre eigene Version der Sprache, die sich mit der anderer Sprecher überschneidet (so daß Verständigung möglich ist). Dies wird deutlich an regionalen Differenzen. Man könnte es vielleicht auf wenig benutzte Dialekte einschränken. Aber ist es noch ein Wort der Sprache X, wenn die meisten Sprecher der Sprache es nicht verstehen?

Weiterhin wird dieses hypothetische Wort wohl nicht im aktiven, sondern nur im passiven Wortschatz sein, da es ja sonst aktiv verwendet würde. Das macht es nochmals problematisch zu definieren.

Zusammenfassend denke ich, daß es nicht möglich ist, ein solches Wort zu finden.

Comment: Das ist, für mich, eine sehr erhellende Betrachtung, und ein gutes Stück auf dem Weg zu einer Antwort. Es lebe hoch die fundierte Sprachphilosophie. Selbst leicht linguistisch angehaucht war mir, gleichwohl, der Gedanke neu (aber einleuchtend), dass es *eine Sprache* gar nicht gibt, sondern nur die Versionen der einzelnen Sprecher. Danke für diese Einsicht!

Comment: Der Begriff Hapax Legomena bezieht sich aber auf einen einzelnen Text. Ein banales Wort wie "Fenster" könnte in den meisten Texten, in denen es überhaupt vorkommt, nur einmal vorkommen ohne deswegen ein seltenes Wort zu sein.

Comment: @userunknown Korrekt. Und natuerlich kommen 'normale' Woerter in manchen Texten nur einmal vor. Wenn man eine Sprache als Summe von Texten (geschrieben oder gesprochen) ansieht, dann gibt es da selbstverstaendlich Ueberschneidungen. Aber ein seltenes Wort kommt halt in wenigen Texten selten vor.

Answer (score 4):

Ein Wort für Dinge, über die man nicht spricht, ist *Tabu*, aber einerseits gibt es den Trotz, doch darüber zu sprechen, oder Situationen, Räume, Personengruppen, für die es kein Tabu ist. So spricht etwa der Darmspezialist über *Scheiße* und man benutzt das Wort zum Fluchen usw.

Darum geht es also offenbar nicht. :)

Das, worum es geht, ist aber eine Unmöglichkeit. Gäbe es das Wort, das bekanntlich am seltensten benutzt wird, würde darüber berichtet und das Wort augenblicklich aus dem Pool der Kandidaten für diese  Position hinaus befördert. Das ist ähnlich wie mit der Zahl, die folgender Definition genügt:

> Die kleinste Zahl, die man nicht mit elf Wörtern definieren kann.

Comment: Mich beschäftigt nun vor allem der Gedanke, ob du die Frage absichtlich missverstanden hast oder unabsichtlich. Gefragt war ja nicht ein Klassenbegriff für Dinge, über die man nicht spricht, sondern ein Wort für ein konkretes Ding. Außerdem meinte ich weniger "nicht sprechen dürfen" (was beim Tabu doch wohl die Hauptsache ist) sondern "nicht sprechen tun, auch wenn man es dürfte ***und*** könnte (weil sowohl das Wort als auch das bezeichnete Ding einfach kein Thema sind).

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: "Interesting question: is there a word in any human language relating to a thing about which nobody speaks?" - darauf bezog sich der Exkurs zum Tabu.

Comment: Ich nehme meinen Kommentar zurück (ich übersah das *nicht*).

Answer (score 0):

Selten verwendet werden Wörter insbesondere dann, wenn sie nicht deshalb in die Sprache kommen, weil sie verwendet werden, sondern deshalb, weil sie uns aufgezwungen werden.

Immer wieder finden sich neue Tier- und Pflanzenarten, die eine Bezeichnung brauchen, und je unspektakulärer die neue Art ist und je weniger sie für Forscher hergibt, umso seltener wird die ihr verliehene Bezeichnung hinterher verwendet.

> Die nächste Bezeichnung, die zwangsweise eingeführt wird, ist unmittelbar nach ihrer
>   Einführung das seltenste Wort der Sprache.

Comment: Ist dann, konsequent weitergedacht, ein Wort nicht noch seltener, wenn es *überhaupt nichts*, was es gibt, bezeichnet und es daher *überhaupt nicht* verwendet wird? Ist nicht *Wrglfrdl* seltener als *Bacillus Hypotheticus*?

Comment: @tofro: Was keine Bedeutung hat, werte ich nicht als Wort.

Comment: Da bist du aber ziemlich hart zu so Wörtern wie "Oh", "Ach" und "jehmine", die alle auch keine Bedeutung haben.

Comment: @tofro: Die haben Bedeutungen.

Comment: Das hängt von deiner Definition von „Bedeutung „ ab. Und da streiten sich viele schon lange drüber

Comment: @tofro   Wenigstens unter den (vagen) Bedingungen der Ausgangsfrage wäre *Wrglfrdl* eher kein hier erörterbares Wort (der deutschen Sprache), da *Wrglfrdl* bisher nichtc *verbucht* ist. (Was sich natürlich mit heutigem Datum dann gehändert hat, denn nun wurde *Wrglfrdl* ja schon vier mal in unser Forum eingetragen.)

Comment: @Ich glaube, du hast da einen Tippfehler drin. ;)

Comment: @Pollitzer: Dann definiere ich jetzt einfach, dass „Wrglfrdl“ so viel wie „Wort ohne Bedeutung“ bedeutet. Und schon hat es eine Bedeutung, und ist daher kein Wrglfrdl mehr. ;-)